# What does error when compiling drivers for wn722n mean?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am trying to install drivers for wireless adapter wn722n on kali linux.
Following TP link manual:https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201812/20181207/Installation%20Guide%20for%20Linux.pdf

I get a lot of errors at the **make** stage that I don't understand:

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222# make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.5.0-kali2-amd64/build M=/root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.5.0-kali2-amd64'
  CC [M]  /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service.h:46,
                 from /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service_linux.h:288:8: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’
  288 |  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
      |        ^~
/root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service_linux.h:289:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  289 |  init_timer(ptimer);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |  _init_timer
In file included from /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/drv_types.h:35,
                 from /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/wifi.h: At top level:
/root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/wifi.h:1012: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 1012 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
      | 
In file included from /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service_linux.h:86,
                 from /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/osdep_service.h:46,
                 from /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.5.0-kali2-common/include/linux/ieee80211.h:1451: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 1451 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
      | 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.5.0-kali2-common/scripts/Makefile.build:271: /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.5.0-kali2-common/Makefile:1707: /root/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v5.2.2.4_25483.20171222] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.5.0-kali2-common/Makefile:179: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.5.0-kali2-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:1911: modules] Error 2
```

Anyone has an idea what those mean?

Comment: your error is `error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’` and also `error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: @Leos313, what you are talking about? What library? This is kernel, no C or other libraries are available.

Comment: You have pretty new kernel where some APIs have been changed. So, you basically need to *forward-port* the driver to your kernel.